# PHP inheritance, class, objects

Tags: php

Book which PHP code is taken from: (the book can be found here - https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KZoAq_mbhXAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) page 37 [The Shop Product Classes).

I have some PHP code (from the book above) but I keep getting errors when I have typed the code?

Code errors:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ShopProduct::getProducer() in ...

If I fix that, I am also getting this error:

> Code errors: Fatal error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function__construct' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in ...

Code:

```
<?php

class ShopProduct {
    public $title;
    public $producerMainName;
    public $producerFirstName;
    public $price;
    private $discount =0;

    public function __construct (   $title, $firstName, $mainName,     $price)  {

        $this->title = $title;
        $this->producerFirstName = $firstName;
        $this->producerMainName = $mainName;
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    public function getProducer()  {
        return $this->producerFirstName;

    }

    public function getProducer()  {
        return $this->producerMainName;
    }

    public function setDiscount( $num)  {
        return $this->discount->$num;
    }

    public function Getdiscount()  {
        return $this->$title;
    }

    public function GetPrice()  {
        return ($this->$price - $this->discount);
    }

    public function GetProducer()  {
        return "{this->producerMainName}" .
            "{this->producerMainName}";
    }

    public function getSummaryLine() {
        $base = "{$this->title} ( {$this->productMainName}, ";
        $base .= "{this->producerFirstName} )";
        return $base;
    }
}

class CdProduct extends ShopProduct {
    private $playLength =0;

   public function__construct(    $title, $firstName, $mainName, $price,     $playLength ) {
        parent::__construct(    $title, $firstName, $mainName, $price,);
        $this->playlength = $playlength;
    }

    function getPlayLength() {
        return $this->playLength;
    }

   public function getSummaryLine() {
        $base = parent:: getSummaryLine();
        $base .= ": playing time - {$this->playLength}";
        return $base;
    }

}

class BookProduct extends ShopProduct {
    public $numPages =0;

     public function__construct(    $title, $firstName, $mainName, $price,     $numPages ) {
        parent::__construct(    $title, $firstName, $mainName, $price, );
        $this->numPages = numPages;
    }

    function getSummaryOfPages() {
        return $this->numPages;
    }

    function getSummaryLine () {
        $base = "$this->title ( $title->producerMainName, ";
        $base .= "this->productFirstName )";
        $base .= ": page count - $this->numPages";
        return $base;
    }

    public function getPrice() {
        return $this->price;
    }   
}

?>
```

Comment: You can't have several methods with the same name

Comment: you have two same function name, `getProducer()`

Comment: Also you have two cases of `public function__construct` - a space is required after `function`. A proper IDE would help you here.

Answer (score 2):

You have two functions that are called getProducer. You should rename one of them

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, PHP doesn't allow multiple function or methods declarations. In your case, the `getProducer()` method is declared twice. Once in line 18, and the second is right below the first declared method. Delete or rename one of them and your code will work again.

Comment: I've changed the function (that is now clear) but I also have the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function__construct' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\Program